# Making registry changes to current user not applying outlook settings

Tags: script, windows-registry, microsoft-access, citrix

I'm attempting to set a handful of registry keys for trusted documents and outlook settings from a batch script I created to launch an application through Citrix.

The script works for the most part, no errors generated when run, but the settings are not being applied to the application. The application itself is just a access database.

When the application is run it copies the files to a remote file server setup for folder redirection in Citrix and then opening the file from that server. I'm wondering if the keys need to be added to that server as well but I'm unsure of how to add HKCU keys to a remote server.

These are all the commands I'm using for the local reg edits

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations" /v AllowNetworkLocations /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location18" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "\\server\share\%username%\workingdirectory" /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations\Location18" /v AllowSubfolders /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\outlook\autodiscover" /v zeroconfigexchange /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\outlook\ost" /v noost /t REG_DWORD /d 2 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\outlook\cached mode" /v enable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\outlook\cached mode" /v cachedexchangemode /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f
```

I'm probably overlooking something here but I don't know what.

Comment: Well I definitely missed an obvious error on the trusted locations path, I forgot to add the second to last directory to the path, saw it as soon as I posted my question. That fixed my trusted locations issue so now all I need to figure out is why the outlook settings are not applying properly.

Comment: updated the title to reflect the specific issue i'm dealing with now.

Comment: Does it work if you specify: HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\...?.

Comment: Are you modifying the Registry on the computer where Outlook is being run? It's not clear from your question exactly where that is.

Comment: Yes it's currently modifying on the local registry, I thinkHelpinghand was right about me omitting part of the regkey path, but correcting that problem didn't seem to make any difference with my issue, calling the outlook function within my database still prompts me to configure outlook which is going to be a problem for me if I leave it that way.